# kendo dropdownlist always select the first option from list

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

the value of this column is East Region Group. But when i click on the select list it always highlight the first option. I do not know what is the problem. Below are the code snippets.

[Dropdownlist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRciK.png)

[PriceGrpList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzsCr.png)

[DefaultPriceGroup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3Oae.png)

```
        var guid = kendo.guid();
        $('<input name="DefaultPriceGroup" id="' + guid + '" class="dropDownTemplate"/>').appendTo(container);
        ddt = $(container).find('#' + guid);

        dataItem = options.model;
        $(ddt).kendoDropDownList({
            name: "DefaultPriceGroup",
            value: dataItem.DefaultPriceGroup,
            dataSource: dataItem.PriceGrpList,
            dataTextField: "Text",
            dataValueField: "Value",
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what is happening is your server-side code to return the DefaultPriceGroup is returning the record's text rather than the record's value (presumably an Id column).

Without knowing the schema of your PriceGroup view model, I'm making an assumption here, but I think you will need to change the server-side code to something like:

```c#
DefaultPriceGroup = _cfgPriceGroupService.GetPriceGroupByPriceGroupCd(x.PriceGrp_cd).PRICEGRP_ID
```

Take a look at this fiddle: https://dojo.telerik.com/AHIteQep